# How to make Facebook Marketing API for Ad Creative using php?

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create an ad creative but getting an invalid parameter error. The exception even does not specify which parameter is wrong.

```
try {
     $link_data = new AdCreativeLinkData();
     $link_data->setData(array(
           AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MESSAGE => 'try it out',
           AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => 'http://www.google.com',
           AdCreativeLinkDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => '704e55dbf724243acfb8457a4f68a92a',
         ));
    
     $object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
     $object_story_spec->setData(array(
           AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
     ));
    
     $creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_576834712392068');
    
     $creative->setData(array(
           AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative Suite CRM',
           AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
     ));
     $creative->create();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e, "\n";
}
```

> Caught exception: exception
> 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message
> 'Invalid parameter'

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not added the Page where the creative has to be posted. I think adding `AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => 'your published page id here'` in `object_story_spec array` will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set your app's status to active from development. It was the reason of the same failure. You can check your error in more detail with

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e)
}
```